# using std::get<>() in std::for_each

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I have a map which is being iterated over in a `std::for_each` loop. I am using a nested bind and simple helper functions to get to the element of the pair I require. This has to be usable from pre c++11 code.

```
typedef std::map<int, Foo> MapType;

std::for_each( 
    testMap.begin() , 
    testMap.end() , 
    std::bind( 
      &Foo::myIncredibleFunction ,  
      std::bind( 
          &ValueExtractor< MapType::key_type , MapType::mapped_type >::getValue, 
          std::placeholders::_1 )));
```

This works fine (although I'm sure could be refined)

***I am also going to be migrating the current code base from the current level to C++11*** and so I am looking at whether I can use new features of the language to improve the code (readability, efficiency). For example I have tried the following (Unsuccessfully - see template error below)

```
std::for_each( 
    testMap.begin() , 
    testMap.end() , 
    std::bind( 
        &Foo::myIncredibleFunction ,  
        std::get<1>(  std::placeholders::_1 )));
```

error

```
    1>d:\projects\test_bind\test_bind\test_bind.cpp(48): error C2780:
    std::bind ...<Snip>...
    : expects 6 arguments - 2 provided
```

also intellisense has the following:

```
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::get" matches the argument list
argument types are: (std::_Ph<1>)
```

I have tried various combinations of usages of `std:get<1>()` to try to replace my inner bind with no success. I suspect that I am failing to understand this properly but it feels like I should be able to do what I want. Is there a way to do this using the `std::get` call and without a helper function/functor?

**Edit:** I think KennyTM has come up with my answer with regard to what I actually do in the code, it's so much better than my approach. I'm still interested in whether `std::get<>` could be used above or why not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using C++11 already, why not use a range-based for loop (which is supported in [VS 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh409293.aspx))?

```
for (auto&& item : testMap) {
    item.second.myIncredibleFunction();
}
```

Comment: That's neat - I'm still catching up with features. I'd be interested in knowing why the std::get<> fails, however this does look to be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `std::get<1>(_1)` is a perfectly fine function invocation on its own.

What you want to do here is called *function composition*, which can be done with nested bind calls, e.g. `std::bind(foo, std::bind(bar, _1))`. The problem here is the second part, where `bar = std::get<1>` - `std::bind(&std::get<1>, _1)` would be the obvious first try, but that doesn't work because `std::get` takes more template parameters.

One solution is a custom function object:

```
#include <utility>

template<unsigned I>
struct get{
  template<class T>
  auto operator()(T&& v) -> decltype(std::get<I>(std::forward<T>(v)))
  { return std::get<I>(std::forward<T>(v)); }
};
```

And then: `std::bind(&Foo::myIncredibleFunction, std::bind(get<1>(), _1))`.

Comment: Right I see, it needs a level of indirection much the same as I did before. I assumed that the template for get would expand out the placeholder into the correct type for the function I wanted to bind to.

Comment: So to improve the code readability I definitely think that KennyTM has the way forward. Thanks for the reply Xeo.

Comment: @Caribou: You're welcome. Note that Kenny's way won't work if the loop is actually encapsulated in some other function, which only accepts a function (object).

Comment: In this instance it isn't the case although I think I will need to bear that in mind when I do the work because the map has several operations performed on it (Some method invocations, some functor ) from some similar code paths - thx again.

Comment: @Caribou: Note that you can also make this look nicer / reuse more things by doing `auto get_value = std::bind(get<1>(), _1);`.